# Delete files older than 365 days

Tags: bash

Files are named like name_2016-01-19_00-00-00...

Tried script like `find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;` but unfortunately the files were moved from Linux to Windows and so forth so the file dates are no longer accurate.

Comment: As I understand it, there is no accurate timestamp. The file name needs to be parsed, right?

Comment: Indeed, the timestamp for creation / modification is not accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will *print* all files that either have no date in the name, or the date is older than whatever you put in the `"dummy_2015_01_27"` name. Once you have the list of names then deleting them is trivial.

It assumes that there will never with an underscore in the `name` part of the filename (i.e. the date is field 2 when split on `_`). If that's not true then you'll have to think of something else.

```
(echo "dummy_2015_01_27"; find /path/to/files -type f) \
    | sort --field-separator='_' --key 2 \
    | sed '/^dummy_/,$d'
```

*This works with GNU sed (I have v4.2.2), which is the favourite on Linux, but probably won't work with other sed implementations. Likewise, I've only tested it with GNU sort (v8.24).*

Comment: good solution, and I would expect your `sed` cmd to work going back to Sun 3 (90's). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shelter the man page suggests the comma operator is a GNU extension. Might be it's a common extension.